# i have an issue with ci-usertracking in get user_identifier

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue with Codeigniter usertracking library , it works perfect but i can't get user_id or i don't know how , i tried to use session library but thats not working. You'll find more informations in this link .[enter link description here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ci-usertracking/wikis/Usage.wiki)
I want to track by User IDs .

```
Use the following format:
|   For Helper Function:    $config['userTracking']['userIdentifier'] = array("helper", "helperName", "helperFunction", "argument array"); 
|   For Library Function:   $config['userTracking']['userIdentifier'] = array("library", "libraryName", "libraryFunction", "argument array");
|   For Helper Function:    $config['userTracking']['userIdentifier'] = array("model", "modelName", "modelFunction", "argument array");
```

Comment: So you are trying to use the logged in person's user_id? The instructions seem pretty clear. So how have you "tried" doing that? You need to show what you have done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I found a solution , I do it with anouther method , just in library Usertracking I added in track_this function : 
`$input_data['user_identifier'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id');`